# Three.js and html slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I've got a problem with mixing `Three.js` and a HTML slider.
The slider is displaying but I cannot move it. When I try to change the value by dragging, nothings happens (only camera moves).

Three.js container:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Slider:

```
<div id="zoom"><input id="setZoom" type="range" min="1" max="9000" step="1" value="100" data-orientation="vertical"></div>
```

Comment: move the slider over the container using z-index:100

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: Can you repeat this problem in a jsfiddle, for example?

Comment: Your question does not give enough information to help you. We can only guess what the problem might be. One guess would be z-index as stated in the first comment (make sure you set the position and z-index css attribute on both divs for z-index to work.) Another guess might be that you are capturing the mouse events so the slider never gets the events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say that your camera is moving when you're trying to change the position of the slider, I dare to assume that you use `THREE.OrbitControls()`.

The solution of such situation can be adding `renderer.domElement` as the second parameter when you create object of controls, like:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/vo1urg68/) example

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the answer as accepted then, please, so the other users can refer to it.